# Rewrite Rule for default directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a number of directories configured like this:

```
/site/[category]/[subcategory]/browse
```

Within each browse folder I have directories named like so:

```
/1-10
/11-20
/21-30
```

and within each of those folders there is an index.html and nothing else.

I want to set up a Rewrite rule such that requests to:

`/site/[category]/[subcategory]/browse` and  `/site/[category]/[subcategory]/browse/`

are equivalent to

```
/site/[category]/[subcategory]/1-10
```

but I want all the other requests to remain the same. For instance I don't want this rewrite to affect requests to

```
/site/[category]/[subcategory]/browse/11-12.
```

Basically I want the /1-10/index.html page to be the default page for the [subcategory] folder.

This is probably quite basic, but between the agonies of apache configuration and regex, I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(site/[^/]+/[^/]+/browse)/?$ $1/1-10/ [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it's not working. I have put this in the root directory and confirmed that mod_rewrite is active. I'll tinker with it and get back.

Comment: What URL did you load in browser to test?

Comment: And .htaccess is inside site directory or at same level as site?

Comment: .htaccess is in /Documents which is the root folder where /site resides.

Comment: I'm so sorry. There was a blank .htaccess file in /site. That was screwing things up. It's working. Again, apologies and many thanks.